# GWAN : How to read cookies

Tags: cookies, g-wan

I'm trying to read cookies but the script below returns an empty string.

```
http_t *http =  (http_t*)get_env(argv, HTTP_HEADERS);
xbuf_t *read_buf  = (xbuf_t*)get_env(argv, READ_XBUF);
char *p = read_buf->ptr;
char *cookies = http->h_cookies ? p + http->h_cookies : 0;
xbuf_xcat(reply, "<HR>COOKIES [%s]<br>", cookies);
```

I have set a cookie previously using : http_header (which I can see in chrome's console)

So how can I read cookies?

Thank you for your answer.

I'm using GWAN 4.11.20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v4.11 was issued without synchronizing the `gwan/includes` headers despite new values being added.

As a result, some of the values used by `get_env()` in G-WAN scripts do not match the values used by G-WAN.

A solution would be to correct these values in the `gwan.h` header. Another simpler way to access cookies is to reach the read buffer using [READ_XBUF](http://gwan.ch/developers#handler) (see the "connection handler" tab) and then look for the cookies using code similar to the G-WAN [cookies.c](http://gwan.ch/source/cookies.c) example.

Paulo, a G-WAN user having the same problem has sent us the following source code:

```
int getSessionID(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    http_t *http = (http_t*)get_env(argv, HTTP_HEADERS);
    xbuf_t *read_buf = (xbuf_t*)get_env(argv, READ_XBUF);
    char *p = read_buf->ptr;
    int sessionID = 0;
    if (http) {
        sessionID = http->session_id;
fprintf(stderr, "Get SessionID %d\n", sessionID);        
    }

fprintf(stderr, "Get SessionID Cookie %d\n", http->h_cookies); 

    if (p && *p && http->h_cookies) {
        char *cookies = p + http->h_cookies;
fprintf(stderr, "Get SessionID Cookie %s\n", cookies);
        // The sessionID is on the Cookie
        sessionID = atoi(cookies + 5);
    }
    if (!sessionID) {
        // The sessionID is not on the Cookie so send the server Session_ID   
        sessionID = (int)get_env(argv, SESSION_ID);
    }
    if (!sessionID) {
        // Oops! I have no session from the Server. use the IP Address and a timestamp
        sessionID = (int)get_env(argv, REMOTE_BIN_ADDR) + getms();
    }
    return sessionID;
}
```

This will get your started.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote simple library for g-wan. You can use it for get cookies.
Example code:

```
char *val = gw_cookie(argv, "cookie_name=", 12);
```

link: https://github.com/fatihky/gwanup/blob/master/gwanup.h#L102

Comment: Your library looks good, but it seems that there is an issue with GWAN 4.11.20 ... So now I'm waiting for next release :)

Comment: I am also using G-WAN 4.3.20 and works properly but I can't updated library yet. It requires hiredis and
'#pragma link "hiredis"'
line in c/c++ scripts.