# GWAN: How to read cookies using php

Tags: php, cookies, g-wan

read about that gwan shall support global variables as $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE, but $_COOKIE won't work?

How is it possible to read them?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

## Set Cookie

```
<?php
   setcookie(“user”,”Angga”);
    setcookie(“user", “nic", time()+3600);
   setcookie(“user", “nic", time()+3600, "/","", 0);
?>
```

## Read Cookie

```
<?php
//Display the value of ‘user’
echo $_COOKIE[“user"]. "<br />";

//This is another way
echo $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS[“user"]. "<br />";
?>
```

## Check Cookie's Status

```
<?php
// Using isset() function
  if( isset($_COOKIE[“user"]))
    echo “Hello " . $_COOKIE[“user"] . "<br />";
  else
    echo “Nothing" . "<br />";
?>
```

## Erase Cookie

```
<?php
    setcookie( “user", "", time()- 3600, "/","", 0);
?>
```

## Update #1

Or try to read this :

[GWAN : How to read cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124249/gwan-how-to-read-cookies)

Comment: No, I'm sorry this won't work as i described in the top.

Comment: $HTTP_* is even deprecated and is not supported by gwan.

Comment: Am sorry, i do not have an experience about gwan. But try to read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124249/gwan-how-to-read-cookies

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP is supported by G-WAN via CGI, you can use the CGI environment `X_HTTP_HEADERS` to read the entire header.